# Only Windows runs after new video card installation

Tags: graphics

I installed a Radeon RX 5600 XT. It runs great...on Windows 10. I can't get it to display on Ubuntu 18 though. I tried purging the Nvidia drivers from the recovery mode terminal which "worked" but when I rebooted the screen was still black.

I also tried installing nouveau drivers from the terminal but it didn't recognize the command.

Any ideas what to try next? I'm a bit stuck here.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure how to help with your issue but I will say that the nouvaeu drivers are for Nvidia cards, not AMD; installing them likely won't do anything to improve your situation. AMD drivers are included in the Linux kernel as well.

Answer (score 0):

When you get to the grub menu you can add the `nomodeset` boot option. `nomodeset` tells the kernal to not load the video drivers until the X window server is started. To add this option do the following:

1. Get to the GRUB boot menu
2. Highlight the `Ubuntu` option
3. Press <kbd>e</kbd>
4. Find the line that has `linux` at the start
5. Add `nomodeset` to the end of that line
6. Press <kbd>Ctrl-x</kbd> or <kbd>F10</kbd> to boot.

Comment: So this got be back into Ubuntu. However, when I tried installing the AMD 16.04 drivers it gave me this screen: https://imgur.com/a/sJfQ0bv 

My ubuntu install was pretty fresh so I decided to just reinstall Ubuntu and when I tried installing from CD I got this: https://imgur.com/a/HVrkhs2

Comment: The first image is normal, there are lines in the second one that say that you hibernated Windows. Try completely shutting down your computer.